# Help troubleshooting foreign relay

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I *believe* I'm sending topic data over a foreign relay, but nothing comes out on the foreign machine

On machine1:

rostopic pub -r 10 /foo /std_msgs/String hello

rosrun foreign_relay foreign_relay adv http://machine2:11311 /machine1/foo /foo

rostopic echo /foo shows a parade of hellos, as you'd expect

on machine 2:

rostopic list shows /machine1/foo

rostopic info /machine1/foo shows  * /foo_foreign_relay_0_adv_1306438093482799609 (http://machine1:54200/)

but rostopic echo /machine1/foo is empty

roswtf on machine2 reports:

ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:

- /foo_foreign_relay_0_adv_1306439078454201491

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

- /foo_foreign_relay_0_adv_1306439078454201491->/rostopic_16013_1306439118679 (/machine1/foo)

suggestions on debugging?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10074/help-troubleshooting-foreign-relay/) by [jrieffel](https://answers.ros.org/users/432/jrieffel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2011-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-05-26**:
Are you sure you posted the right command? The call to foreign_relay should be: 'rosrun foreign_relay foreign_relay adv http://machine2:11311 /machine1/foo /foo', i.e. the master port separated by a :, not by a /. Probably just a typo but to be sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed.  The problem was caused by the two computers being on separate subnets of our academic network, and any number of firewalls existing between the two subnets.  Once both computers were given IPs on the same subnet and in the same network, foreign_relay works perfectly.

(yes, those are typos above, I will try to edit them)

---

Originally posted by [jrieffel](https://answers.ros.org/users/432/jrieffel/) with karma: 39 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roboviz](https://answers.ros.org/users/685/roboviz/) on 2011-07-26**:
I Fixed my problem as well:  http://answers.ros.org/question/1554/successful-use-of-wifi_comm

**Comment by [roboviz](https://answers.ros.org/users/685/roboviz/) on 2011-07-19**:
I am having a similar problem, In my case it's an Ad-Hoc network using olsrd.My subnets both set to 255.255.255.0. Although the new topic is being filled with data noting is being transferred over the network. The new topic is visible on the other machine but remains empty. Help appreciated Thanks